# how to encode/hide my ip address url in php?

Tags: urlencode, url-encoding

Currently I have a hosting in amazon ec2 instance.Now I want to encode / hide the url ip address bar `http://**.***.**.**:80`

Comment: By a domain and set that up perhaps?  You might include more details as this sounds similar to "how can I hide my house from the street so no one knows my address"  You say PHP but do not add that tag to your question.  Please provide more substance to the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create a new/custom domain and configure the same in you amazon settings. Check the links below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjA9MyzUJNQ

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=63753

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your site will be hosted, you can buy a domain with an external company, and point a DNS A record to your EC2. I would recommend getting an Elastic IP address and attaching it to your EC2 if you are going down this road.

If you want to make use of the whole AWS eco-system, you can use Route 53:
https://aws.amazon.com/route53/. This will allow you to purchase and manage the domain directly in the AWS console

If you need any more help, feel free to send me a personal message. I recently had to do this, so have some experience.